# Take a param from the home page, without it breaking the routes

Tags: node.js, express

Let's say I have myWebsite.com and myWebsite.com/login

I have a route for the index page and a route for the login page.

I am working on another feature now, which will take an id such as myWebsite.com/t9wfhash

If there is such id, I will query the DB with it for something.

I tried something like

```
/* GET index page. */
router.get('/:urlId', function (req, res) {

  if ( req.params.urlId !== 'undefined' ) {
    console.log(req.params.urlId);
    var urlId = req.params.urlId;
  }

  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    res.redirect('/dashboard');
  }
  res.render('index', { title: urlId });
});
```

However, the login page doesn't work anymore when taking an id from the index page (:urlId) -- if I go to my login page it just console logs "login", of course.

So how can I make it so if someone goes to one of my routes (IE login page), then it's not considered like an ID.

Any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you register the login route before the urlId route, a request for `/login` will trigger your login route instead of the urlId route:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.send('hello world');
});

app.get('/login', function(req, res){
  res.send('this is the login page');
});

app.get('/:urlId', function(req, res){
  res.send( req.params.urlId );
});

app.listen(3005);

// http://localhost:3005/login will return "this is the login page"
// http://localhost:3005/22 will return 22
```